# Cannot host website on my personal server

Tags: iis-7, web, router, portforwarding, port80

I am not able to host my website on my personal server. I am using IIS7. I have already forwarded the port number 80 on my router and configured my firewall to allow incoming connections on port 80. The strange thing is that I am able to access SQL Server databse from outside which is running on port number 1433 but not my website. Please help.

Comment: Maybe your ISP is blocking port 80? Did you try mapping it to another port, like 8080, for testing?

Comment: yes i did....but only port 1433 is working and i am running sql server on that port....

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Good point but 8080 being also somewhat standard might be blocked as well, I'd suggest trying something non-standard, e.g. 81, 72 etc.

Comment: Try stopping the SQL service and testing IIS on 1433, just to see if it still works.

Comment: Ok i will try...but strange thing is that only sql server is working properly...means it can be accessed from outside...but other servers are not working like my website running on port 80, TFS server running on port 8080, Counter strike server running on port 27015 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.....i was having an issue with port forwarding thing...Earlier i opened up port number 1433 first then port 80 second the port 27015 third...in this order...now i channged the order ie 80 first then 1433 then 27015....strange but it worked...!!